# Is the use of "firebrand" to refer to a piece of burning wood antiquated?

Tags: word-usage

I didn't actually know about this original definition of the word and never heard it used that way.  I thought the word "firebrand" only applied to people.

Comment: It's disturbing that Collins and RHK Webster's do not follow AHD's and ODO's lead in putting the more widely-used sense first in their lists of senses. I believe that they claim to list senses in order of frequency of use (OED, being a historical dictionary, listing in order of first recorded use) None of these add the caveat 'archaic' to the literal sense, but I do think it is rarely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is still used, though perhaps not terribly often.  Here is one example: https://www.balihai.com/Blog/kauai-north-shore-the-spectacular-fire-throwing-ceremony/

There's also a Firebrand BBQ in Australia: https://firebrandbbq.com.au/ and Firebrand wood pellets: http://www.firebrandwoodpellets.com/